# Partial fractions and sum of power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Im wondering how to split given power series with partial fractions (or somehow else). For example I have 
$$ \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{4^n(n+1)(n+2)} $$
Should I just ignore $x^n$ and continue like this?
$$ \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}= \frac{A}{(n+1)}+\frac{B}{(n+2)}$$

Comment: Why would you have $C/4^n$ in a partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: No idea whatsoever

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition is used on rational functions. That is functions which are ratios of polynomials. $4^n$ is not a polynomial term and so cannot be decomposed in such a way. If you want to use partial fraction decomposition in this case, you can only decompose the $\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}$ term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{4^n(n+1)(n+2)}=\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{x}{4})^n}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{x}{4})^n}{(n+1)}-\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{x}{4})^n}{(n+2)}$$
$$=1+\frac{x}{4}\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{x}{4})^n}{(n+2)}-\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{x}{4})^n}{(n+2)}$$
$$=1+(\frac{x}{4}-1)\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{x}{4})^n}{(n+2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Recall that $$\frac{a}{bc}\equiv\frac{\frac ab}{c}$$ so you can rewrite this as:$$\sum\frac{(\frac x4)^n}{(x+1)(x+2)}=\sum\bigg[(\frac x4)^n(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2})\bigg]$$